# Does Bitcoin have a legal expert/team that does their work?

Tags: legal

Does Bitcoin have a legal expert/team that does their work? (yes, they - a group of interested individuals (the Bitcoin team) even though they have no formal association - are a decentralized network but some of those decentralized networks do have offices, etc., and may have a legal team.)

Are there any private individuals who have (ever) started an action on behalf of Bitcoin?

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you are asking.  Bitcoin isn't a "they", of course, and when you say "their work" I don't know what work you mean.  There are plenty of organizations who seek to promote the currency; perhaps the best-known is the Bitcoin Foundation, but there are others, and of course lots of private companies that provide Bitcoin-related services.  No doubt many of them have lawyers.

Comment: I suppose that a group of interested individuals (the Bitcoin team) even though they have no formal association could be 'they'. I will re-word a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BITCOIN is a software ecosystem, and not owned by "someone". Similiarily you could put some code [echo "hello world"] on github, and it would be publicly available. Then there is also no "they", or an association managing the code. The bitcoin developpers are a group of loosely coupled "geeks/freaks", and anyone with a good skill set could belong to this group, by participating in coding/translating websides/correcting wording ... For sure you know that. So as this developer team provides (a highly sophisticated) software, they are not dealing with regulations from each country, in which the software could be used. But I think your point goes into this direction:

There are companies using this public domain ecosystem (kraken, bitfinex, hitbtc, bitcoin.de, blockchain.info). These companies (and some miners) provide ramp-ups and -downs, to make it easy for you and me to use the bitcoin eco-system. They are for sure under a jurisdiction, within their appropriate countries. And for sure "they" have legal/compliance teams, that deal with country specific regulations (aka "KYC/KYI/...").

Still I am not clear on what you suppose by "their work". I think it would be fair to say, Bitcoin doesn't need any work at the legal level. Countries and governments (or other power structures over individuals) need such things, so it is up to "them" (these power structures), to make sure, bitcoin is used in a way, that it complies with their rules of keeping tidal waves of change away from their protected environment :-)

Comment: "their work" - the work of a loosely associated group of individuals. I am not so concerned about Bitcoin that it might need legal defence. I am concerned about the actions of others, their offensive, misleading and deliberately deceptive tactics and what "Bitcoin" may be able to do about that. Actions of others that harm Bitcoin, harm Bitcoin's reputation and harm consumer, business and community understanding of Bitcoin. And, in those things, harm the value of Bitcoin, harming all holders of BTC and miners of Bitcoin in the process. I am considering an evangelical project...

Comment: If my wallet held 1000BTC I would have started several private actions already, in defence of "Bitcoin". I am not concerned by competition, I am concerned by offence.

Comment: ahh, I see, you want to have a protection of the efforts, that were spent into this technology. Good point! I am not aware, that there is some people doing this "actively". All the communication/events/forums for sure help, to spread the message (security, independency, reliability, future proof, fork protection, ...). This is not "coordinated" in a way, that I am aware of. That's what you're looking for?